# Joomla 4. Call to a member function getTable() on bool

Tags: component, administrator, joomla-4

I am adapting the component to the new structure and classes of joomla 4. I started with the admin panel of my component. The list and the edit page are displayed without errors, but when I try to use any toolbar buttons, I get a message.

```
Call to a member function getTable() on bool

Call stack
#   Function --- Location
1   () --- JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/FormController.php:307
2   Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\FormController->cancel() ---JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:730
3   Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute() --- JROOT/libraries/src/Dispatcher/ComponentDispatcher.php:146
4   Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher->dispatch() ---JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:389
5   Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent() --- JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:143
6   Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch() --- JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:186
7   Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute() --- JROOT/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:278
8   Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute() --- JROOT/administrator/includes/app.php:63
9   require_once() --- JROOT/administrator/index.php:32
```

The controller is triggered, so is the model. The model has a getTable() function. Theoretically, everything works, but when 'save', 'closing', or 'save and close', I get the same error. At the same time, the chain of methods does not reach the component model.

**JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/FormController** has no access (or connection) to my model.
The path to the model is **administrator/components/com_mycom/src/Model/NameModel.php**. I don't understand what the reason is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution has been found. My controller contained a **__construct()** function of this type:

```
class MyviewnameController extends FormController
{
    function __construct( $config = array() )
    {
        $this->view_list = 'list';
        parent::__construct( $config );
    }
}
```

I looked at the **com_content** component controller and saw that now **__construct()** contains additional parameters and added them. My problem was solved immediately.

```
class MyviewnameController extends FormController
{
    public function __construct($config=array(), MVCFactoryInterface $factory=null, $app=null, $input=null)
    {
        parent::__construct($config, $factory, $app, $input);

        $this->view_list = 'list';
    }
}
```